# deploying to Heroku: freezes up during "writing objects"

Tags: git, deployment, heroku

I've been trying to deploy my app to heroku, but during the "writing objects" phase (at 10% to be precise) the deployment freezes. Meaning, it stays like that as long as the terminal is open, or I abort the operation (Ctrl+C).

I'm working on a PC, with Aptana 3, and the project is a Rails Application.
I tried reinitializing the Git repository, reinstalling the app on Heroku, updating gems, restarting Aptana, but I'm still baffled.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: This is normally a connectivity problem.  Have you tried taking Aptana out of the equation and running the git push from the command line?

Comment: I tried pushing from cmd as well, and it froze in the same step, so I suppose it's something else in this case

Comment: after trying everything else, it was rebooting my machine that made the problem go away...

Comment: Hey @hananamar, glad you solved the problem! You should paste your answer into the answer box, below, and mark it as 'accepted'. This will help other people find your answer :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I faced the same problem then I found:

`git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000`

it works for me, HAPPY CODING

Answer (score 0):

after trying everything else, it was rebooting my machine that made the problem go away...

I know it's not an official solution, but it did solve it in my case.

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything I found, turning ON the security options.
I know it's another an unofficial solution, but it did solve it in my case.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).